# How can I use an exception inside an while loop? list index out of range

Tags: python, twitter

I have the following function:

```
def findTweetWith100PlusRTs():
    global tweet_main
    while tweet[tweet_main]["retweet_count"] < 100:
        tweet_main += 1
```

It loops through tweets from a list, and finds tweets that have more than 100 retweets.

The problem is, after a while this often happens:

```
File "bot.py", line 41, in findTweetWith100PlusRTs
    while tweet[tweet_main]["retweet_count"] < 100:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This error breaks the script.

How can I make my script not stop when that happens, and run a function that refreshes the list so it doesn't run out of range?

I'd like to use something like this inside the while loop:

```
except IndexError:
    time.sleep(120)
    refreshTL()
```

How would one use an except inside the while loop?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: is there any reason why you have `tweet_main` as a global variable?

Answer (score 2):

While you *can* make this work, you should be using a for loop:

```
# this is a proper use of while! :-)
while True:
    for current_tweet in tweet:
        if current_tweet["retweet_count"] < 100:
            # do something with current_tweet
            pass

    time.sleep(120)
    refreshTL() # make sure you put a new list in `tweet[tweet_main]`
```

If, as can be guessed, `refreshTL()` adds more tweets, you should read on [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and iterators, which are what you want to be using.

A very simple example of an endless tweet generator would be:

```
def tweets_generator():
    tweets = None
    while True:
        # populate geneartor
        tweets = fetch_tweets()
        for tweet in tweets:
            # give back one tweet
            yield tweet
        # out of tweets, go back to re-populate generator...
```

The generator is constantly re-filled with tweets if you implement `fetch_tweets`. Now you can do something like:

```
# only take tweets that have less than 100 retweets thanks @Stuart
tg = (tweet for tweet tweet_generator() if tweet['retweet_count'] < 100)
for tweet in tg:
    # do something with tweet
```

Comment: use a different name for the loop variable in `for tweet in tweet[tweet_main]:` otherwise you will be constantly redefining the list of tweets.

Comment: You could then do `popular_tweets = (t in tweet_generator() if t['retweet_count'] >= 100)` to make an endless generator of the tweets with 100+ retweets.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
def findTweetWith100PlusRTs():
    global tweet_main
    while True:
        try:
            if tweet[tweet_main]["retweet_count"] >= 100:
                break
        except IndexError:
            # do something
        tweet_main += 1
```